# ZLE: Key bindings codes list

Tags: zsh, zle

I know that in

```
bindkey '\ep' autosuggest-accept-suggested-small-word
```

the `\e` refers to the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key. I also know that `C-` refers to the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> key.

Is there a list referencing all the keys because I have the hardest time to understand how ZLE works and which key combination I should use to bind `autosuggest-accept-suggested-small-word` to a keyboard shortcut starting with the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key.

For example: To which keys are these keybindings referring: `^~u`, `~w`, `^@j` (these are keybindings that I found in the [ttscoff keybindings settings file](https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings/blob/master/DefaultKeyBinding.dict))?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` in ZSH (and many other softwares; see for example `stty -a`) refers to <kbd>control</kbd> key e.g. for <kbd>control-L</kbd> to clear the screen one might find in the ZSH keybindings list

```
% bindkey | grep clear
"^L" clear-screen
%
```

I cannot comment on how `^~u` `~w` `^@j` in the ttscoff keybindings relate to ZSH. That software appears unrelated to ZSH; the full list of what ZSH recognizes can be found in the `zshzle(1)` manual, which for some version of ZSH (do instead check the manual for the version you have and do not blindly assume that this list is correct for that version of ZSH) includes

```
          \a     bell character
          \b     backspace
          \e, \E escape
          \f     form feed
          \n     linefeed (newline)
          \r     carriage return
          \t     horizontal tab
          \v     vertical tab
          \NNN   character code in octal
          \xNN   character code in hexadecimal
          \uNNNN unicode character code in hexadecimal
          \UNNNNNNNN
                 unicode character code in hexadecimal
          \M[-]X character with meta bit set
          \C[-]X control character
          ^X     control character
```

To make the Apple <kbd>command</kbd> key generate codes in the terminal requires that the terminal program be configured to do so; the instructions for this will vary depending on whether you are using `Terminal.app` or `iTerm.app` or something else (dig around in the preferences or check the manual).

With `iTerm.app` (this may change; GUI apps tend to move things around over time) try the iTerm2 menu, Preferences, Keys, find the widget to add something, and then "send hex code" `0x02`

[image: send hex code 0x02]

Then in ZSH `bindkey` this sequence

```
% xxd
^B
00000000: 020a                                     ..
% screencapture -s hexcode.png
% bindkey '^B' clear-screen
%
```

and now splat-shift-option-O should cause ZSH to clear the screen; instead `bindkey` your desired widget and set that in your configuration:

```
bindkey '^B' autosuggest-accept-suggested-small-word
```

or whatever other binding that works for you. Be sure to run `bindkey` and inspect that no other existing widget that you want to use uses the key code...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your are they are not related to ZSH. As it looked similar to what I saw in the ZLE documentation I thought they were related. I am using iTerm 2 at the moment.

Comment: @thrig if the 'xxd' and 'screencapture' lines are irrelevant, in that one code snippet, can we remove them? (I was about to edit but didn't want to break something without realizing)